# What clean, comfortable, affordable hotels are within a 5 minute walk of Moscone Center in San Francisco?

Tags: budget, hotels, san-francisco

A friend [tweeted](https://twitter.com/#!/isaiah/status/154261561307955200) about how expensive the hotels near [Moscone Center](http://www.google.com/search?q=moscone%20center) in San Francisco are (for Macworld).  I've tried more reasonably-priced hotels near Union Square (which isn't too far a walk), but none of them are worthy of a recommendation.

In most cities, I'd set the bar of affordability lower, but this is San Francisco, so let's say under $200/night.  (And ideally the hotel has free, reliable WiFi or in-room internet.)

Comment: Hi Daryl.  Could you be more specific? Are you looking for the cheapest? Or the one closest to the center? We try to get questions on here that can be answered objectively, and at present, it's rather subjective...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the law of supply and demand means there are no cheap hotels near the Moscone Center. Your best bet is probably an outlying hotel and the bus. Or relax and enjoy your $180 broom closet.

Comment: I just edited the question and description to be more specific and hopefully objective enough.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Hotel Fusion](http://hotelfusion.com/) just off union square; it's more of a 'European-style' budget/boutique hotel, I stayed there the weekend before xmas last year and thought it was fine, was < $100/night then for a single room (actual single, with a real single bed!). WiFi was free, small continental breakfast included too. Recommend checking out the reviews on Tripadvisor before booking; if you're expecting something Hilton-esque with large rooms, it's likely not for you, but if you want something that falls between hostel and Hilton, it may fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

[Macworld 2012's own site has a page on hotel accommodation](http://www.macworldiworld.com/2012travel/) with quite a few hotels mentioned in the price range you want (~$200/night). If you [click through to their partner site for hotel bookings](https://resweb.passkey.com/go/MW12), you can also sort through a list of hotels closest to Macworld venue sorted by distance (search for rooms on particular nights, then use the 'distance' sort on results page).